# Cannot install pip install numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C:\Users\Mtronics>pip install numpy
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Mtronics>
```

Comment: `pip3` or `python -m pip` or `python3 -m pip`

Comment: You need to add `pip` path in env variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"`
if it is not working install your python modules like this `python -m pip install [packagename]`